# Drupal 7 custom block.tpl.php for specific region

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I am new to drupal 7 and really struggling with this one:

http://drupal.org/node/104319

I have a region called navigation

in my .info
`regions[navigation]     = Navigation bar`

for this region I want to use a custom tpl.php file. I have tried

```
  block-navigation.tpl.php
```

like in the example, and put it at the theme root and in the templates folder with no luck. I've cleared the cache and insured that a standard working block.tpl.php is in place. To no avail.

ANSWER:

I needed BOTH a region--navigation.tpl.php AND a block--navigation.tpl.php with a double `--` both times.

**1000 views** on this question earned me the popular question badge. But you guys can't find it in your heart to **upvote** it more than **1** time. Laaaammmmmeeee....

Comment: Regions are for different Blocks,  Try creating same block with different theme. Add visibility configuration using page arguments.

Comment: So its not be region but by the block itself?

Comment: Yeah. But lets wait some minutes for other solutions.

Comment: here we go, +1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a custom tpl.php file for "navigation" region, you should use region--navigation.tpl.php

Comment: Dang it. It need to be the block. Its main menu if that helps.

Comment: If you need to use "block-navigation.tpl.php", you should also have a custom block.tpl.php for your theme. See this(http://drupal.org/node/104319) for more details.

Comment: That documentation page is for Drupal 5. http://drupal.org/node/1089656 is the appropriate documentation page for Drupal 7. The relevant naming pattern is block--[region].tpl.php and the generic template (block.tpl.php) is no longer needed in D7 in order to use a specific template (block--[region].tpl.php).

Comment: After looking at "block-navigation.tpl.php" in the question, I was misled. Sorry, for the confusion I caused. ty sheena

Comment: All good. I am just here to learn ;)

Comment: FYI, for Drupal 6 the pattern is "block-[region].tpl.php".